# Bandmatrix number of nonzero elements

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have got a bandmatrix $A^{r \times r}: (a_{ij})\in\{0,1\}$ with its bandwith $n$.

If $n$ is odd, the band is symmetric around the diagonal. If $n$ is even, the band has one more upper diagonal.

The problem is that I can't find an explicit equation to calculate the number of nonzero values (the number of elements of the band).

Answer (score 0):

Consider the first case, $n$ being odd. Then of course you have $r$ nonzero numbers on the diagonal. Furthermore you have $\frac{n-1}{2}$ diagonals with entries in both directions and each of them contains $1$ element less in each direction away from the diagonal, i.e.:

$\# nonzeros = r + 2 \sum_{k=1}^{\frac{n-1}{2}} (r-k)$. For this expression to evaluate, use e.g. Wolframalpha.

Now consider the second case, $n$ being even. It's of course almost the same, i.e. use the result for $\tilde{n} = n-1$ and then it remains to add the nonzero numbers for the remaining upper diagonal, i.e.:

$\# nonzeros = r + (2 \sum_{k=1}^{\frac{n-2}{2}} (r-k)) \ + \ (r-\frac{n}{2})$.